# Passing arguments from batch to powershell

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I have a batch file, from where I run a powershell script. I would like to pass arguments to this powershell script. I have tried many different things:

```
Set MachineName=Computer2
%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -Command "%~dp0%\Rename.ps1" -MachineName %MachineName%
```

and with `-File` instead of `-Command`

```
Set MachineName=Computer2
%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -File"%~dp0%\Rename.ps1" -MachineName %MachineName%
```

and without the named parameter `-MachineName`

```
Set MachineName=Computer2
%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -File"%~dp0%\Rename.ps1" %MachineName%
```

My Powershell script (Rename.ps1) starts with:

```
Param($MachineName)
```

I have tried with double quotation, single quotation, no quotes, using -File using -Command, using named parameter (like `-MachineName`) and without the named parameter but I get this error every time:

> Processing -File '\10.193.40.56\c$\systems\cph_wsconfigtool\src\scripts\MachineName' failed because the file does not have a '.ps1' extension. Specify a valid Windows PowerShell script file name, and then try again.

However, it works perfectly fine if I remove the argument. So what am I doing wrong? I have read every post I can find on the internet about it, and they all say this is the way to do it.

Comment: `%~dp0%` -> `%~dp0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
-Command "%~dp0\Rename.ps1"
```

instead of

```
-Command "%~dp0%\Rename.ps1"
```

(Answer pulled from comments on original question.)